# Desktop Environment/Architecture in Android and Linux

Tags: android, linux

I'v been reading about the differences and similarities of Android and Linux distributions. I'm aware that beside the linux kernel, there are enormous differences between these two

```
systems -> Keyword Java
```

There's is one thing that's not clear to me. Android's graphical environment, is this just a java application as well? So, do i interpret [such](https://www.google.at/search?q=android%20architecture&espv=2&biw=1362&bih=651&tbm=isch&imgil=FEKTPp_XSVRQ_M%253A%253B8-29jajJPdjacM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.edureka.co%25252Fblog%25252Fbeginners-guide-android-architecture%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=FEKTPp_XSVRQ_M%253A%252C8-29jajJPdjacM%252C_&usg=__HzFsLILddZqKOl3Otp20-jgytfY%3D&ved=0ahUKEwjBq5-_wJnRAhUGWhoKHY9OAocQyjcILQ&ei=_A5lWMG9DIa0aY-dibgI#imgrc=FEKTPp_XSVRQ_M%3A) graphics correctly and `Dalvik` is the only application that runs above the kernel, and the other stuff is virtual, while on a Linux System, the Desktop environment is native (and the JRE is just one native applications)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very briefly, when Android boots up, bootloader starts kernel like other general Linux distros (with some extra devices like Binder, etc). Kernel does its initializations and starts init. init sets up the user space differently. init starts a few housekeeping daemons (native, non java). In it's later stages, instead of running desktop environment, it starts a generic java process (using jre) called zygote which is forked to start all new other android processes. First 2 of which are system services and launcher (Home screen). launcher acts as the graphic environment for user to launch other apps similar to desktop environments in Linux.